# Window app development

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows

I am totally new in Windows app development, and wondering whether the application developed for, let's say, Windows mobile 8.0 will work on Windows mobile 7.8 and Windows RT, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, OR there is need to adapt the application?

I would really appreciate any tutorial to have an understanding what to do not to fail.
Thanks.

Comment: Well first I would say don't call it Window Moblie lol its Windows Phone. You're question is hard to answer. Yes, some code can be used across all platforms. Most of your UI related code cannot though.

Comment: Could you please provide any link to guide or a tutorial?

Comment: Windows Phone 8 applications will not run on Windows Phone 7.x. Windows Phone 8 can run in *Quirks Mode* to allow executing applications written for Windows Phone 7.x. On the desktop things are a lot less troublesome. In general, Windows 8.x (running on Intel platform) can execute just about any Windows application, desktop or modern UI. Sharing code between desktop and mobile platforms is possible; the platforms have a large overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the answer

1. Windows Phone 7.x apps can run on Windows Phone 7.x & 8.0 (reverse not possible)
2. Windows Phone apps can't run on Windows 8
3. Current desktop apps can run on Windows 8 (not Windows 8 RT)
4. Current Windows 8 (or Store) apps can run on any Windows 8 device

If you want to build an app which should run on all devices i.e. Windows Phone 7.x and above, Windows desktop, Windows 8 etc... You can separate the user interface part and business logic. There is something called as Portable Class Libraries. You can use them to share the code between apps.

For more information:
http://mayurtendulkar.com/2013/09/cross-platform-hybrid-or-native/
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Hope it helps.